# Can't save xml file content in mysql with fopen/fwrite/fclose (php)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, file, blob

So I'm writing an **XML** file in php with fopen/fwrite/fclose and then attempting to save that information into a MySQL database **BLOB** field; however, I'm running into an issue where after saving the information into MySQL, all the file contains is **"Resource id #33"** and none of the information that I was trying to save.

```
$blahXMLFile = fopen($_POST['scenBlahNewName'].".xml","wb");
fwrite($blahXMLFile, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>");
fwrite($blahXMLFile, "<Blah>");
fwrite($blahXMLFile, "<Name>");
fwrite($blahXMLFile, $_POST['scenBlahNewName']);
fwrite($blahXMLFile, "</Name>");
fwrite($blahXMLFile, "</Blah>");
fclose($blahXMLFile);

$sql = "INSERT INTO blah (xmlFile) 
                      VALUES ('$blahXMLFile');";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else { echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error . "');</script>";
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    } //end else
```

And then after that I take the **$blahXMLFile** php variable and try to save it in the **BLOB** field in my MYSQL database and "**Resource id #33**" is all that's in the file. This is also the case if I use javascript to alert the php variable.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Trying to use fread here correctly based off of a comment:

```
$blahXMLResource = fopen($_POST['scenBlahNewName'].".xml","w");
$blahXMLFile = fread($blahXMLResource, filesize($_POST['scenBlahNewName'].".xml"));
```

Because that isn't saving a file at all anymore.

Comment: Since when do you write to database with fwrite?

Comment: I'm not using fwrite to actually save the content in the database, just to write to the file; I use sql queries, but what I'm trying to figure out is how exactly to save the CORRECT information, because none of that content is being saved, just Resource id #33.

Comment: Make sure to check for errors after `fopen()` with appropriate diagnostics on failure. Make sure to properly sanitize the user input in `$_POST['scenBlahNewName']`. Add intermediate diagnostic prints to make sure you really know which file the data is being written to.

Comment: What is `wb` mode? Where are you trying to write to the `db`? Sounds like you are trying to write the `fopen`s resource. Use `fread` to read the contents. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: wb is the same thing as w; as stated in the post it's a blob field; what I'm trying to write is everything within the fwrites, but the resource ids is what's actually being written in the end for some reason that i'm not aware of.

Comment: Post your actual DB write.

Comment: Done, I edited it into the main post for readability under the fwrites. xmlFile is the BLOB field.

Comment: See comment #1.`$blahXMLFile` is the resource. `fopen() binds a named resource, specified by filename, to a stream.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: So then should I be starting my file write more like this? (check edit in main post).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95968/discussion-between-michael-anthony-leber-and-chris85).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I got it; after advice from @chris85 I replaced my fopen/fwrite/fclose with file_put_contents (I was using file_get_contents, but that was appending rather than overwriting the files each time).

```
$blahXMLFile = $_POST['scenBlahNewName'].".xml";

$blahXMLFileContent = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<Blah xmlns='uri:/mil/tatrc/physiology/datamodel' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation=''>   
    <Name>".$_POST['scenBlahNewName']."</Name>
</Blah>";

file_put_contents($blahXMLFile, $blahXMLFileContent);

echo "<script>alert('".addslashes($blahXMLFileContent)."');</script>";
```

$blahXMLFileContent is what I eventually put into the MySQL database.